# backtrace_symbols fails to print the very function that has caused the signal

Tags: c++, macos, stack-trace, callstack, signal-handling

I'm implementing a simple crash logger for my C++ application:

```
static void handler(int, siginfo_t * info, void *) {
    void *array[1000];

    switch (info->si_signo) {
    case SIGILL:
        Logger() << "Received SIGILL";
        break;
    case SIGSEGV:
        Logger() << "Received SIGSEGV";
        break;
    case SIGBUS:
        Logger() << "Received SIGBUS";
        break;
    case SIGSYS:
        Logger() << "Received SIGSYS";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
    const size_t size = backtrace(array, 1000);

    // print out all the frames
    char ** symbols = backtrace_symbols(array, size);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        Logger() << symbols[i];
    }

    free(symbols);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct sigaction SignalAction;
SignalAction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
SignalAction.sa_sigaction = handler;
sigemptyset(&SignalAction.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &SignalAction, NULL);
sigaction(SIGBUS, &SignalAction, NULL);
sigaction(SIGILL, &SignalAction, NULL);
```

I haven't tested it on Linux yet, but on OS X the specific trace item that I'm interested in, the one thatr has caused the signal, is *not* being printed (entry number 2):

```
: " Received SIGSEGV" 
: " 0   App                       0x0000000100253d15 _ZL7handleriP9__siginfoPv + 229" 
: " 1   libsystem_platform.dylib  0x00007fff8ff0f5aa _sigtramp + 26" 
: " 2   ???                       0x000000000000000c 0x0 + 12" 
: " 3   App                       0x000000010000dfa7 _ZN11CMainWindow13initShortcutsEv + 231" 
: " 4   App                       0x000000010000d059 _ZN11CMainWindowC2EP7QWidget + 1001" 
: " 5   App                       0x00000001000091d9 main + 6217" 
: " 6   App                       0x00000001000070a5 _start + 227" 
: " 7   App                       0x0000000100006fc1 start + 33"
```

Why is this happening, and can I fix this?

P. S. This is a debug build. There was no actual segfault, it was simulated with `raise(SIGSEGV)`. `raise` was called from a method , that, in turn, was called from `MainWindow::initShortcuts`.

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be, and how do you know this trace is wrong? It's possible that either stack corruption has occurred (messing up the back trace) or the process actually tried to jump to address 0xC (due to memory corruption, programming error, etc).

Comment: Well, since you're using C++, you could also derive from `std::exception`, build your stack trace info in an `std::list` of `std::string`s in the constructor of that derived exception class, and throw that derived class. As the answers show, you can never rely on a signal handler to give a correct stack trace.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: please see updated question (the footer - P. S. section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entry number 2 has very special address. It's 0x000000000000000c and you have to know that there is interrupt description table. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table it may be Stack Fault.

However as Ken pointed, doing what you are doing is bad. It's like trying to remember license plate of car that hit you when you aorta is torn apart. You can do it but what for?

Maybe instead of doing it try learn how to use strace http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace.

Comment: Strace doesn't seem to do what I need.

Comment: Hmm, as I understand this trace log, Stack Fault was caused by `: " 3   App                       0x000000010000dfa7 _ZN11CMainWindow13initShortcutsEv + 231"`, processor looked up interrupt desciptor table (entry 2) and jumped to procedure handling this signal in `libsystem_platform.dylib` (entry 1) which invoked again your code (entry 0) because you set your own signal handler. IDT is a list of jump instructions to interrupt handlers.

Comment: There was no stack fault. There was `SIGSEGV` signal. And it was sent not by `ZN11CMainWindow13initShortcutsEv`, but by another method called from there.

Comment: Debug build, no optimizations. Shouldn't have been inlined.

Comment: It doesn't matter it's Debug, if you defined code in header it would probably be inlined. Methods also may be inlined. Make it virtual so it for sure won't get inlined.

Comment: You're wrong. No optimization = no inlining, else you wouldn't be able to debug properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46588/discussion-between-omikron-and-violet-giraffe)

Answer (score 3):

The idea of building a crash logger with a signal handler is fundamentally flawed. From the "NOTE" section of the [sigaction man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> The following functions are either reentrant or not interruptible by
>   signals and are async-signal safe. Therefore applications may invoke
>   them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions:
>
> [… async-signal safe function list omitted …]
>
> All functions not in the above lists are considered to be unsafe with
>   respect to signals.  That is to say, the behaviour of such functions
>   when called from a signal handler is undefined.  In general though,
>   signal handlers should do little more than set a flag; most other
>   actions are not safe.

None of `backtrace()`, `backtrace_symbols()`, `free()`, or `exit()` are safe to call within a signal handler. Almost certainly, stuff within your `Logger` or `operator<<` is also unsafe.

As to why the signal-provoking function is not in the backtrace, it's evidently cause by how the signal handler context is set up by the kernel. A backtrace is obtained by examining stack frames as constructed by call statements and function prologs. A signal handler is not invoked as a normal function call, so there's no particular reason to expect that the chain of stack frames would be set up properly.

In fact, signal handlers can be made to run on a completely different stack than normal code. See [`sigaltstack()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/sigaltstack).

Comment: The link at the very end of your post, which is the only part that might actually be useful to anyone, is now dead.

Comment: link is dead now, see `man sigaltstack` or https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Stack.html.